# where condition for year and month

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause

I have a datatable with year and month columns. I store these values as number, like 2014 and 1 for jan 2014, etc.

Now, I would like to select all values between 2014-01 and f. e. 2015-5.

I have tried it different ways (between the two values, concating them), but it exists always values, which the result set don't contains.

How should be look the query?

Comment: Couple Questions: What database are you using? What datatype are the months and year columns? Most databases have specific date datatypes so that you don't have to do fancy calculating to grab a range. If you aren't taking advantage of your DATE datatype, you might want to look into that.

Comment: I use ms access, the month and year column are integers.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. At the end, I inserted a new column in the table, where I store the first date of the corresponding year and month.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable m
WHERE CDate(m.month & "/1/" & m.year) Between #1/1/2014# AND #5/1/2015#
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want:

1. All data from 2014
2. 2015 data from Jan through May

If that's correct, you can ask Access to give you those data directly ... without the need to first transform your year and month fields to a date value.

```
SELECT *
FROM datatable
WHERE
    year_field = 2014
    OR
    (
        year_field = 2015 AND month_field <= 5
    );
```

With *year_field* and *month_field* indexed, this query should be much faster than an alternative where you apply `CDate` or `Format` to every row of the table and thereby forego any opportunity to benefit from indexed retrieval.

On the other hand, if your table is small enough, you probably wouldn't notice the horrible inefficiency.  :-)

Comment: As long as he has the correct data type.  ;o)  Otherwise 10, 11 and 12 are gonna come back (when data for those months is entered into the DB).

Comment: He said *"month and year column are integers"*.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the two parts of all of the involved parameters into actual dates and use BETWEEN on them instead.

```
SELECT [field_list]
FROM [table_name] t
WHERE CDate(t.year + '/' + t.month + '/02') 
  BETWEEN #2014/01/01# 
      AND #2014/05/03#;
```

If you have an actual day field you can use that, but for simplicity, and assuming you aren't using the day, the above setup should work fine for you.

Comment: `convert()` is not valid in MS Access.

Comment: Your query will still not work.  As it is it would produce a **Data type mismatch** error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining your RBDMS, so I'm supposing you use ORACLE, you can change the syntax of course.

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE (SELECT to_date(to_char(year) || '/' || to_char(month) || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
       FROM dual)
BETWEEN (SELECT to_date('year/mm/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd' FROM dual)
AND (SELECT to_date('year2/mm2/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd' FROM dual)
```

Untested.
Notice you need to replace year and mm for the beginning date and year2 and mm2 for the ending date.

Comment: The OP is using MS Access.  Your query will not work in MS Access.

Comment: I was writing the post before reading he used MS access. Please read the first line of my answer.

Comment: **@fmbesteiro**, I did read your answer, just like you should have read the question and comments first.  **derstauner** stated 9 minutes before you posted your answer that he/she was using MS Access.

Comment: I started writing the answer many minutes before, it's just I went AFK and then finished it and posted.

Answer (score 0):

I got yelled at one time because `between` is not safe apparently, so you may prefer

```
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE AS m
WHERE Format(m.month & "/1/" & m.year,"mm/dd/yyyy") >=
      Format(#1/1/2014#,"mm/dd/yyyy") AND
      Format(m.month & "/1/" & m.year,"mm/dd/yyyy") <=
      Format(#5/1/2015#,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Also base code stolen from Linger